# How to handle more than 11 dependencies to a task in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on an sbt plugin where a task needs to depend on more than 11 keys:

```
someKey <<= (a1, a2, ..., a12) map someFunc
```

It won't compile because the implicit conversion `map` function (e.g. `t#ToTable#`) only goes up to 11.

Is there a better design pattern I should be using when I have a bunch of keys/dependencies all feeding into one function?

Comment: What, no Spinal Tap jokes yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
someKey := someFunc(a1.value, a2.value, ..., a12.value)
```

More generally `.value` is preferred, as it reduces the number of symbols, with simpler ones like `:=`/`+=`/`++=` over `<<=` and other variants.

Comment: Thanks much. Good to know what's considered more readable too.